# failure of sending multiple messages

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, sms

I have a Samsung Galaxy S (GT-i9000), running Android 2.3.4.
I cannot send a message that includes more than one page of SMS. The message sending fail if it includes more than 160 characters. I can send only one page of SMS. Guess it's a kind of an edited version. That version came with the brand new phone. The phone does not work with ''ginger bread'' or ''ice cream sandwich''.
What should be done to make it clear?

Comment: Just to clarify: The device is running Android 2.3.4, but does not work with Gingerbread -- so it does not work at all currently? Hint: Gingerbread = Android 2.3.x :)

Comment: SMS messages over 160 characters are often sent as MMS messages - confirm with your provider that MMS service is active on your line and that the APN settings for MMS are correct on your phone.

Answer (score -1):

Go to `Settings > wireless and network > mobile networks`.
In the network mode, select GSM only.
I was having the same issue, and this step solved the problem.